# Vietnamese spell check

Tags: 20.04, ibus, language-support, unicode, spell-checking

Spell check in Ubuntu doesn't work for Vietnamese tone marks. The spell check for 'có' is not the same as the spell check for 'có'.

The first (typed with Ubuntu) has this unicode:

111     006F     o     LATIN SMALL LETTER O

769     0301     ́     COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT

The second (from Google Translate) has the correct unicode:

243     00F3     ó     LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH ACUTE

How do I use Ubuntu to type Vietnamese correctly so that the second unicode is used?

$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'vn')]

Comment: I use the one that comes with Ubuntu. I installed Vietnamese language from the Ubuntu settings. I'm not sure which is the default tool.

Comment: I get this output:
[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'vn')]

Answer (score 1):

After receiving a lot of patient assistance from Gunnar Hjalmarsson I have been able to partially solve the issue. The unicode output from Unikey does pass the spell checker (if using Telex input method). However I use VNI input method and that doesn't work on Unikey.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use the pure Vietnamese XKB layout.

There are other tools available for typing Vietnamese. I would suggest that you install these two packages:

```
ibus-unikey
ibus-m17n
```

Then, after next reboot, you'll find a few more input source options for Vietnamese in *Settings -> Region & Language*.

My hope is that one of those options will make a difference. I'm not sure about it, but my idea is that you explore those other input methods and find out yourself.

Comment: I'll try it and post the results when I restart.

Comment: I'll try to be concise but it is difficult to explain properly.
I tried all the options that unikey and m17n gives me. I already had unikey as an option so there was no change with installing it. Some of the m17n options seem to be for Chinese. I tried the VNI option, which is the method I use to type, but I was unable to get the tone marks or diacritics with this method. I also tried the TELEX method and was able to get the tones but I get the same result with incorrect spelling.

Comment: @Hilton: I see. Myself don't speak Vietnamese, so I'm not able to explain how you actually use those input methods. But when you say that you already had the Unikey option, it looks from that `gsettings` output that you hadn't added it. Saying this to make sure that we don't talk past each other.

Comment: Ok. I understand what you mean about unikey. I tried the gsettings output and get this:
[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'vn'), ('ibus', 'm17n:vi:vni')]
But when I try to install ibus-unikey I get the message that it's already installed.

Comment: @Hilton: Yes, the package may have been _installed_ when you installed the Vietnamese language. But to be able to try it out you also need to _add_ Unikey in the settings, so Unikey is added to the list of available input sources.

Comment: Yes. I understand. So I have the following input methods:
en
vi1 (what I was using before)
vi2 (unikey)

Comment: @Hilton: I just installed `ibus-unikey` myself and added it in Settings, and as a result the source `('ibus', 'Unikey')` is included when I run that `gsettings` command. I didn't see that source in your `gsettings` output which is the reason I keep asking about it. :)

Comment: I see what you mean. I guess I must have missed a step somewhere.

Comment: When I go to Settings > Language and Region, I see under input sources: English (US); Vietnamese; Vietnamese (Unikey)

Comment: I think unikey is corrupted. I'll uninstall and reinstall it.

Comment: @Hilton: If you see Unikey there it has actually been added, and you should be able to switch to it and try it out. But in that case you should see it when running the `gsettings` command too.

Comment: This is strange. I uninstalled unikey and it now shows in gsettings.
[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'vn'), ('ibus', 'Unikey')]

Comment: Aha. I removed unikey from sources and now it is gone. I'll re-install it. I guess the install didn't work.

Comment: @Hilton: Right. They should show the same thing, which is why I was confused before. So if you install the package again, relogin, add it back in Settings, are you then able to switch to Unikey and try it out?

Comment: Ok. I've got Unikey in gsettings and listed under sources in Language & Region. Sadly there is still something wrong. I can't select the VNI input method. It is listed but when I select it, it snaps back to the previous setting.

Comment: @Hilton: That sounds as a bug which I can't reproduce. Which Ubuntu version are you on?

Comment: I'm using 20.04 LTS

Comment: 5.4.0-58-generic

Comment: @Hilton: Then you have an older `ibus-unikey` version than me. You may want to upgrade it from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gunnarhj/+archive/ubuntu/ibus-unikey).

Comment: I've updated ibus-unikey to your version on the PPA. It seems the selection works now. However I am unable to use VNI input. The keyboard layout isn't correct. I should see the tone markings and diacritics on the line for the number keys. But the view is not showing me that.

Comment: @Hilton: I see. That problem is over my head. The only remaining advice I'm able to provide is that you try [this project](https://github.com/BambooEngine/ibus-bamboo#readme). `ibus-bamboo` is not an official package in Debian/Ubuntu, but the developers make it available in a PPA.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts in trying to solve the issue. I had a quick check, now that I know about unikey, and it seems to be a common issue. Hopefully the unikey devs might solve it.